# Clean regex matches with named matches

Tags: php, strings, regex

I have a regex pattern that will match some elements from a string and give them a particular name. For example, `#^(?<foo>.*)$#` will match the whole string and name it `foo`.

My problem is that the matches also contain the "classic", numbered matches.

For example:

```
<?php

$pattern = '#^(?<foo>.*)$#';
$str = '123';
$matches = null;
preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

will print:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 123
    [foo] => 123
    [1] => 123
)
```

As all the matches will always be named, I decided to manually remove the numbered indexes from `$matches` in order to clean things up:

```
<?php

$pattern = '#^(?<foo>.*)$#';
$str = '123';
$matches = null;
if (preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches))
{
    foreach ($matches as $key => $value)
    {
        if (is_int($key))
            unset($matches[$key]);
    }
}
print_r($matches);
```

Which prints:

```
Array
(
    [foo] => 123
)
```

It works, but I feel that it can be improved. Is there a better way to do this, especially without the `foreach` loop?

In practice, `$pattern` and `$str` can be much more complicated than the example I gave and I want this to be executed as fast as possible.

Comment: The pattern doesn't match.  I think you have a typo? The last `^` should perhaps be `$`.

Comment: Do you _know_ the named keys in advance? Because if you do, you can use `array_intersect_key`.

Comment: Please improve this question.  As it is written, there is no reason to use regex (a possible fringe case being that you don't want to match strings that contain a newline character). The logic in the snippet is effectively produced by: `$array = ['foo' => $str];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've looking for the same solution as you. But after finding your solution and additional research I find this way to do it, which does not contain a loop.

```
$pattern = "#^/article/(?<id>\d+)-(?<slug>.+)$#";
$url = "/article/42-is-the-answer";

preg_match($pattern, $url, $args);
print_r($args);

$args = array_filter($args, 'is_string', ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
print_r($args);
```

Output :

Without array_filter() :

```
Array
(
    [0] => /article/42-is-the-answer
    [id] => 42
    [1] => 42
    [slug] => is-the-answer
    [2] => is-the-answer
)
```

With array_filter() :

```
Array
(
    [id] => 42
    [slug] => is-the-answer
)
```

Comment: that is an alternative solution, not a review of the existing solution

Comment: Yes it does appear to be an alternate solution but bear in mind that the OP asked “_Is there a better way to do this, especially without the foreach loop?_” and it has justification: “_I find this way to do it, which does not contain a loop._”.

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ Was this implementation possible when the question was posted?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review, could you weigh in on whether or not this was available to the OP at the time of the original post?  I agree with @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ that in this case it could be considered a review.  but if it wasn't available to the original poster, then I would suggest that it is at the very least noted in the answer.

Comment: @pacmaninbw yes the latest version of PHP available as of 03 Sep 2015 was [PHP 5.6.13](https://www.php.net/releases/index.php#5.6.13) and [the code produces the same output in that version](https://3v4l.org/cGr4G#v5.6.13)

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ I changed the accepted answer to yours because it's quite simple and clean. Thanks for that !

Comment: @FrancoisBaveye I am not the author of the answer- merely an editor

Answer (score 4):

If you know what the named matches are up front (ie if you know what the pattern looks like, you can simply use `array_intersect_key` to extract only the values that have a specific key from the `$matches` array:

```
$names = ['foo' => null];

$pattern = '#^(?<foo>.*)$#';//changed ^ to $ at the end ;)
$str = '123';
if (preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches))
{//or return here
    $matches = array_intersect_key($matches, $names);
}
return $matches;
```

Of course, if you are *not* in control of the names that will be used in the pattern, you'll have to *either* iterate over the `$matches` array like you're doing now. However, I'd recommend you *don't* use `unset` on the `$matches` array, but rather copy the relevant values to a new one and return that array instead:

```
$returnValue = [];//new array
foreach ($matches as $k => $v) {
    if (!is_int($k)) {
        $returnValue[$k] = $v;
    }
}
```

There are a couple of reasons for this:

- It's considered bad practice to change the array you're iterating over inside the loop. It can cause issues in certain cases, and it will definitely bite you if you decide to pick up another language
- PHP's memory management and copy-on-write mechanisms work well with code like the loop above: the new array will be assigned a reference to the value in `$matches`, but once the function returns, `$matches` is GC'ed. The values not referenced by `$returnValue` will be GC'ed, the other values are then *"owned"* by the return array (that's not 100% accurate, but it's true enough for now)
- It's probably the most efficient (in terms of readability *and* execution time) approach.

#### Time to get silly

Just for the fun of it: you can opt for an inception-style `preg_match_all` call on the regex you're passing to `preg_match` (regex matching on a regex... let's be honest, that sounds a tad absurd). It's silly, but it *can* be done:

```
$pattern = '#^(?<foo>.*)$#';//changed ^ to $ at the end ;)
$str = '123';
$names = null;
if (preg_match_all('/(?<=\?<)([^>]+)/', $pattern, $matches))
{//create an assoc array containing the match names
    $names = array_fill_keys($matches[0], null);
}

$matches = null;
if (preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches))
{
    if ($names) {
        //gets only the named keys
        $matches = array_intersect_key($matches, $names);
    }
    return $matches;
}
//throw exception, return null, or do something else here
```

Now, this is not exactly the way to go, but in some cases it might happen that you're processing a string, but what regex you apply to it can change depending on any number of reasons. In that case, `array_intersect_key` is definitely worth a look, seeing as it only returns the keys that exist in *all* of the arguments you pass to it:

```
class Foo
{
    const DOMAIN_PATTERN = '/(?<=@)(?<domain>[^@\.]+)(?=\.)/';//or something
    const EXTENSION = '/\.(?<extension>[a-z]{3,4})$/';

    protected static $names = [
        'domain'     => null,
        'extension'  => null,
    ];

    protected $mode = null;

    public function setValidationOptions(array $options)
    {//based on these options, one or more specific regex's will be applied to the data
        $this->mode = $options;
        return $this;
    }
    public function validateString($string)
    {
        $regex = $this->getPatterns();
        $result = [];
        foreach ($regex as $pattern) {
            if (preg_match($string, $pattern, $matches)) {
                $result = array_merge(
                    $result,
                    array_intersect_keys(
                        $matches,
                        static::$names
                    )
                );
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

This is just a crude example of how you *could* use `array_intersect_key` to handle regex matches with named sub-patterns

Answer (score 2):

Considering that PHP will always output both named and numeric indexes (also tried with `preg_match_all`), and considering that the next piece of code expects an array with named indexes only, there's no other way (that I could think of) than to go through all items in the array and unsetting the numeric-indexed items using `foreach` and `unset`.

Besides, considering that you're saying that the pattern and subject might be much more complex, the "clean-up" procedure time should be negligible compared to the execution time of `preg_match`.

If going through all items using `foreach`, testing and unseting them takes a significant time, I would suggest moving the tests into the code that will use the array, and if `!is_int($key)` then process the value  according to your requirements.

Comment: _"If going through all items using foreach, testing and unseting them takes a significant time"_ You state this right after saing that the _"clean-up"_ procedure time is negligible compared to `preg_match`. Also: moving the code that processes the `preg_match` return value doesn't reduce complexity of the overall code base, nor does it reduce execution time (because the processing is still being done, it's just moved elsewhere). It's quite likely to end up being duplicated several times over, even... Lastly: a `foreach` without `unset` is probably the fastest way to go

Comment: I said that the clean-up SHOULD be negligible. That does need testing and proof. Also, as OP said that he "want[s] this to be executed as fast as possible". His solution is simple and works but involves an extra step that could be cut down: going through all items, unsetting them, then going through all items again - my suggestion is just go through every item and process them if it matches the condition (not is int).

Comment: What condition are you talking about (if not `is_int`)? Conditions to see if the match actually matches the pattern that is used? That doesn't really make sense. Admittedly, I've not read the question in great detail, though...